# Creating SharePoint View with Distinct Column value

Tags: listview, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, distinct

Is it possible to create a custom list view (Not a list view webpart) with unique column value. I have one list which has 5 column like project ID, Project Name, Activity ID, Status, Points.

I want to create a Custom list view where the Activity ID column should be return distinct value only. How Can I achieve this goal? Please help to do this. All suggestions and answers will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint List views are based on CAML queries and CAML does not support retrieving DISTINCT values yet.

What you can do is use GROUP BY, which will group all the similar results together and you can optionally collapse it as well, looking like a distinct rows.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c2bbcf13-a53d-4755-87dd-871a51840a4d/select-distinct-in-caml-query-for-list