# Grouping list items to display in a bar chart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a list that is used for keeping records of taskings. The list contains a calculated column that creates a string to categorize the list items based off a few other fields and date. I would like to display a bar chart that can group the like items and display a count but I'm having difficulty displaying the data. To simplify I have data similar to this:

```
Title    CalculatedColumn
foo1      "2014 Q1"
foo2      "2014 Q1"
foo3      "2014 Q2"
bar1      "2014 Q1"
bar2      "2013 Q4"
```

Now I want to display a bar chart showing:

```
2013 Q4 - 1 item
2014 Q1 - 3 items
2014 Q2 - 1 item
```

How do I filter the data from the list to group and count like items? Do I need Visual Studio to perform that kind of calculation or can it be done with SharePoint Designer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381623/creating-sharepoint-view-with-distinct-column-value/23381704#23381704

Comment: I have tried the `Group By` option and this give exactly what I want to base the data off of (including a count for items in group) but I cannot create a bar chart with that data. I need is the count for number of items in each Group but for some reason sharepoint cannot plot that data.